# How to use combination of (hard coded values and input values from csv file) in Jmeter script. I need to read specific coulmn values from CSV

Tags: jmeter, parameterization

I am trying to send this JSON payload in request data from Jmeter and I want to read PaymentID and Parts:[ "field2"] from .csv file that has some extra coulmns, any help in this regard?
1) How to read specific columns as input values from .csv file?
2) How to read JSON object values from .csv file?

**Payload:**

```
{
   "Location":"xxx",
   "Payment":
   {
       "Source": "xxx",
       "SourceID": "123456789",
       ***"PaymentID": "",***
       "PaymentType": "xx",
       "PaymentForm": "API",
       "CustomerNo": "xx",
       "PaymentDate":"18 SEP 2018",
       "Amount": "xxxx",
       "TaxCode": "Sxx",
       "Operator": "",
       "TillNo": "",
       "Description": "",
       "Parts": [
            {
            "field": "xxx",
            ***"field2": "xx",***
            "field3": "xx"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to provide the exact solution without seeing your CSV file, basically there are 2 options:

1. (Preferred) You can declare all columns as [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and use only those, which are related to the columns you're interested in
2. (Alternative) You can use [__CSVRead() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) where you can specify which column to read

   [image]
3. You can inline JMeter Variables or Functions directly into JSON Payload:

   ```
   {
      "Location":"xxx",
      "Payment":
      {
          "Source": "xxx",
          "SourceID": "123456789",
          "PaymentID": "${Variable_From_CSV_Data_Set_Config",
          "PaymentType": "xx",
          "PaymentForm": "API",
          "CustomerNo": "xx",
          "PaymentDate":"18 SEP 2018",
          "Amount": "xxxx",
          "TaxCode": "Sxx",
          "Operator": "",
          "TillNo": "",
          "Description": "",
          "Parts": [
               {
               "field": "xxx",
               "field2": "${__CSVRead(your_file.csv,4)}", ${__CSVRead(your_file.csv,next)}
               "field3": "xx"
               }
           ]
       }
   }
   ```